# How do I get the status.podIP within the container program in GCP Cloud Run?

Tags: .net, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, orleans

I am trying to run a container image in GCP Cloud run.

Tech Stack:
.NET 6, C#, Orleans.NET, ASP.NET

My code requires the podIP to work properly.

This programs works properly in a regular Kubernetes cluster, because I am able to set an environment variable with the assigned podIP with the following configuration in the "env" section of the deployment.yaml file:

```
  - name: POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
```

When I try to provide the same in Cloud Run yaml, I get:
[image: GCP Cloud Run - YAML Edit]

When I tried digging into the documentation of k8s.io.api.core.v1,

[GCP Documentation - Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rpc/k8s.io.api.core.v1#k8s.io.api.core.v1.EnvVarSource)
[image: GCP Cloud Run - Documentation]

This is saying that "Not supported by Cloud Run".

Is there any way to set podIP in the environment variable of GCP - Cloud Run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run is a serverless product. As serverless product, you don't manage the servers and the network. Therefore, asking for the podIP make no sense and has no value (at least, it will be a private IP in the Google Cloud serverless network).

So, the answer is "NO, you can't get the podIP".

But why do you need it? You can set a dummy value and see what happens we your container. Or to update your code to make optional that value.

Comment: I understand. The podIP seems to be requisite of the Orleans Framework. I believe perhaps this framework requires a proper cluster.

Comment: By reading the docs, Orleans framework seems compliant with Azure cloud and kubernetes. No room for other deployment.

Comment: Yes, in the documentation it only specified Azure Cloud. But, the Orleans framework imposed no such restriction. If it is a Kubernetes cluster, we should be able to deploy Orleans to it.

Comment: Cloud Run is not hosted on Kubernetes but on Borg. Borg is a Google Made orchestration system (with a lot of C++ in it). Kubernetes has been built on the lessons learnt with Borg and some improvement (I guess the extensibility). Even if the behavior of Borg and Kubernetes are very similar, the API, CRD or other are totally different.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for the Information.